# Howto: Locate a Resource file within a JAR file without knowing the name and location upfront

Tags: java, jar, lookup, manifest.mf, meta-inf

General problem: finding/locating a resource file (document.xml) within a JAR file that has no fixed position where it can be found and even the name of the file is unknown upfront.

Situation: two JavaSE projects, both create own JAR file. `Jar-A` holds a xml document somewhere within the jar (location not known upfront). `Jar-B` wants to ask `JarA` to hand over the document for a certain operation (e.g. settings information). The caller,     `Jar-B` doesn't know how what the resource/file is called, and where its current location within `Jar-A` is.

Requirements: `Jar-B` should be dependent of fixed locations of resources/files in     `Jar-A` because resources can be renamed or moved around within `Jar-A`. `Jar-B` should ask `Jar-A` where the file is and how the file is called it is looking for.

Possible solution direction:
The `META-INF` directory always holds a `MANIFETS.MF` file with key/value pairs. So, if I store a key called 'ResourceLocator' and a value like 'org.my.package.ResourceLocator.class', then `Jar-B` can find the class it can load to instantiate a locator object that can give out the correct name and location of the file it is looking for, right?

The resourcelocator can be used for more values to be looked up this way.

Having a resourcelocator object within `Jar-A`, only the keys to reference to 'things' need to be documented, but the actual implementation is decoupled from the outside world.

I am wondering if this is a good approach to deal with this kind of lookup? I already know about the `Netbeans Lookup API`, but that needs a class/interface name for the lookup. That is not what I am looking for right now.

Any ideas how to make sure the `Jar-A` and `Jar-B` stay decoupled when searching for resources not known upfront?

Note: this is not some service loader or extersion mechanism, because that would be the other way around: `Jar-B` needs to be found by `Jar-A`. Which is not the case here. `Jar-A` doesn't know of any existence of `Jar-B`.

Hopefully someone came across this 'problem' already. Please share your ideas... Thanks!

Link to JAR Specs: [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JARs are ZIPs. Java has decent native support - seems solid enough - to open JAR-A and paw through the files inside (ZipFile.entries Enumeration.)

That assumes you can locate JAR-A on the filesystem, which from the sound of your description, I'nm guessing that JAB-B knows exactly where JAR-A is located.

Comment: Jar-B could be a GUI in which the location of Jar-A can be set (e.g. preferences). So, yes Jar-B knows where to find Jar-A. But Jar-B doens't know anything of the internals of Jar-A (not making it classpath dependent).

Comment: If the location of Jar-A can be configured in GUI then why not configure the resource locator class(that exists in jar-A) too?

Comment: @srikanth yaradla: please eleborate on this idea. I am not quite sure if I understand what you mean. I want Jar-B to know nothing about Jar-A, but only its physical location. From that point on the Jar-B should sniff inside the Jar-A by looking up the class location of the ResourceLocator from the MANIFEST.MF file and go from there. This way I can rearrange any content without breaking external code (Jar-B) references.

Comment: Why put that resource locator information in Manifest? when you have the luxury of  specifying it externally in GUI? (along with the location of Jar-A) Jar-B would then use this class to load the resource?

Comment: @srikanth yaradla: The resource locator needs to be in the manifest of Jar-A because of two reasons: 1. using the manifest to look up the resourcelocator class makes the external interface decoupled (Jar-B doesn't have a direct link to the resourcelocator class, so refactoring of Jar-A doesn't break any code in Jar-B), 2. In the GUI the location of Jar-A can be anything (no fixed location for Jar-A). The location of Jar-A is set by the user, and can point to different versions of Jar-A.

Comment: Hmmm. I still don't understand what difference it would make if you configure the class in UI .For Manifest you would still need a key (harcoded in Jar-B?) to identify that class value . Why not allow the user to configure both the jar and the resource locator class in UI. It is still decoupled right?

Comment: @srikanth yaradla: using a key (string value) makes it easier to decouple, because there is no direct relation to a hardcoded class which Jar-B references in Jar-A. This way I can document the string value as the key to ask for the resourcelocator. If I decide to refactor or change the code of Jar-A, Jar-B still can find the correct class though the manifest call.

Comment: is the file not always named "document.xml"? If you don't know the name of your file, or it's path, then yes, you'll absolutely need some other means of passing the full path through, and the MANIFEST.MF seems like a fine place.. If you know there's only one file with that name, then ZipFile should work, too. Maybe a combination of the two - open the MANIFEST.MF, find the real path, and then use the ZipFile class to read that file.

Comment: @Brad Tofel: yes, that is what I have in mind: fully decoupled between the Jars. I don't know the document name or it's resource locator of that Jar (in this example Jar-A). So reading key/value pair from MANIFEST.MF returns the actual class name as a String. The key can be documented as the way to get the class name that Jar-B can instantiate and go from there... Doing it this way gives me the freedom to change anything (except the key value in the MANIFEST.MF) in Jar-A over time (refactoring/moving classes and filenames). I love it when a plan comes together :)

Comment: If you are using Jar-A as just a zip and Manifest.MF to locate the resource then there is no need for resource locator class(you could very well define the path of that resource file in Manifest instead of class and read that resource using zip utils). But in the question you said `'So, if I store a key called 'ResourceLocator' and a value like 'org.my.package.ResourceLocator.class', then Jar-B can find the class it can load to instantiate a locator object that can give out the correct name and location of the file it is looking for, right` . To be continued

Comment: Continuee..How exactly are you going to instantiate this resource class in JAR-B. You would need some common interface to read the values returned by the resource locator class (Which is what Gilbert answered below). You also mentioned in the comments that `Doing it this way gives me the freedom to change anything (except the key value in the MANIFEST.MF)` If the value (resource class fq name) is not going to change then is this not an overhead? i.e., reading the Manifest.Mf and fetching the class fqname from Jar-B? Just my thoughts :) Upto you what you want to implement.

Comment: @srikanth yaradla: Never thought about it to just give the full path to the resource in the MANIFEST.MF directly, without using a resourcelocator class. Another thing is: what if a ResourceLocator object (in Jar-A) is instantiated (within Jar-B): how does Jar-B know the methodnames to call on ResourceLocator obj? Then these methods should also be mentioned in the MANIFEST.MF file, and let Reflection find the methods in the class. This is somehow getting awkward :)

Comment: You don't need to configure method names you could use the methods in the interface to retrieve the values (which is what Gilbert already answered). How did you plan to implement this in first place when you said  this `So, if I store a key called 'ResourceLocator' and a value like 'org.my.package.ResourceLocator.class', then Jar-B can find the class it can load to instantiate` ?

Comment: @srikanth yaradla: My intension was to not have Jar-B a direct class reference into Jar-A. When Jar-B reads the MANIFEST.MF key/value, it gets the full className of the ResourceLocator. Then the [class.forName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) method is used to instantiate an object from it. After that run an init() method or so.

Comment: This is what i have been telling from the beginning you dont need to rely on the Manifest to get the class fqname. You can get that from UI itself and avoid the overhead of reading the Manifest file.It is till decoupled. Now how exactly are you going to call that init. You would call it using the interface. The accepted answer is not exactly related to the question. Given the description in the question i found Gilberts answer the most appropriate. But brads solution can also be tried if you are not planning to use any references of Jar-A in Jar-B.

Comment: @srikanth yaradla: Gilberts solution uses a class reference that Jar-B needs to call on Jar-A. Brads solution doesn't (that is also what I have in mind). Gilberts solution is "fixed" in terms of the path/package and classname. I want to avoid the scenario that Jar-B depends on the internals of Jar-A directly, but when Jar-A gets modified in such a way that the direct reference is moved to another place, Gilberts solution won't work anymore. That's my concern (troubled thinking). I do not want Jar-B referencing something directly in Jar-A. The manifest solution solves this problem.

Comment: Did not know that Gilberts solution was fixed in terms of classname. But still even with that dynamic loading using class.forname theres no need to lookup the manifest for that resource class.You can lookup that class using simpler means (UI/config). Anyways its your decision

Answer (score 0):

Jar-A accesses the resource file internally using `getClass().getResource()` or `getClass().getResourceAsStream()`, whichever is more appropriate.

Jar-B accesses the resource file using a Jar-A publicly defined access method.  In other words, Jar-A is added to the classpath of Jar-B, and a method in Jar-B acceses the resource file using a `public Resource getMethod()`;

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you mean by "publicly defined access method"? Do you mean a look up through the MANIFEST.MF file in the Jar? I think the [java.util.jar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/package-summary.html) package can help me with this...

Comment: @Gilbert he doesn't want to add Jar-A in Jar-B's classpath. He wants to load that resource class dynamically (which in turn loads the resource) see the comments in other answer

Comment: Yes, that is true what srikanth yaradla says: Jar-B gets an exact path/file pointer to the Jar-A (entered by the user in the GUI of Jar-B). Jar-B doesn't know the internals of Jar-A, and also doesn't know the exact filename/location of filename in Jar-A. That should be looked up using the MANIFEST.MF file of Jar-A. This way Jar-B stays independent of Jar-A (no fixed code logic). The MANIFEST.MF of every JAR is always in a fixed location and can easily be read using the `JarInputStream` class. Key/value pairs in MANIFEST.MF reveal the exact name/location of the file in Jar-A I am looking for.